# Where does MacBook save Sierra OS update files for Mac, not iPhone?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update

I downloaded an update today and had to click "install later." Now, not sure where that update is. Where does MacBook save Sierra OS update files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/Library/Updates​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Just commenting to confirm. This is indeed still where macOS Mojave downloads its updates, or at least a primary location for that.